# how to list a column that a name appears more than once but match two different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has details of actors, movie_title, character, year_rel. I need to run a query to list the actors that played more than one character in the same movie. I have tried various select statements with no luck.

I have tried

```
select title, actor, char_name
from actor
GROUP BY actor
having count(char_name) > 1;
```

Although there is one result displayed that didnt play two roles in the same movie but did appear in two different movies

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT().

Comment: i have tried                                                              select title, actor, char_name from actor 
GROUP BY actor
having 
 count(char_name)>1;  Although there is one result displayed that didnt play two roles in the same movie but did appear in two different movies

Comment: You're close, try `GROUP BY actor, movie`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see if an actor has more roles than movies:

```
select actor
from actor
group by actor
having count(*) > count(distinct movie_title)
```

Or if an actor has more than one role in a movie:

```
select actor, movie_title
from actor
group by actor, movie_title
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: I tried this: select title,char_name, actor from actor 
GROUP BY actor,title
having 
 count(char_name)>1 ; Which worked and i also tried your suggestion which is a good alternative thank you.